# PolarProxy ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, ssl

My environment is Linux Kali in virtual marchine and I am trying to decrypt the SSL/TLS from an ELF program.

For that I am using PolarProxy, I download the application for linux and configured the iptables commmands :

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 10443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to 10443`

After that, I added the cert certificate into my linux system from this tutorial from the official website : https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy

After that I started the polarproxy application in command line :

`sudo ./PolarProxy -v -p 10443,80,443 --certhttp 10080 -w ~/polarproxy.pcap`

And after that, I started the application and got this error :

**15:42:46.794 › Error: Error: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

and I got more information on polarproxy :

```
<6>[10443] Active tasks : 1
<6>[10443] 10.0.2.15:10443 -> ?:443 Connection from: 10.0.2.15:39150
<6>[10443] 10.0.2.15:10443 -> github.com:443 Connection request for github.com from 10.0.2.15:39150
<3>[10443] 10.0.2.15:10443 -> github.com:443 Internal TLS session Exception: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
<6>Saving debug log to /root/.local/share/IsolatedStorage/dccflvfb.pfg/yzjhnzrw.jtk/Url.2wipyxq23b2qzm44ql2b3al5pbwgor5r/AssemFiles/_220312-154130.log
<4>[10443] ?:10443 -> github.com:443 Internal SSL session did not authenticate successfully
<6>[10443] Active tasks : 0
```

I Thinks it's about the certificate but If people can help me it's will be amazing because I am really lock.

Thanks.

Comment: See if this article helps:  ......    https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/neterr-cert-authority-invalid/

Comment: Thanks for the article but the problem is not a browser application it's from an ELF program so I don't know how I can do to fix this issue.

Comment: The "Internal TLS session Exception" error message means that the problem lies between the local client application and PolarProxy. The error message from the client application also indicates that it doesn't approve of the root CA cert from PolarProxy. Possible reasons for this could be that either PolarProxy's root CA wasn't properly configured as trusted by the OS or the application doesn't use the OS's trusted roots to verify the CA. Which application is the "ELF program" that you're running?

Comment: Hi Erik thanks for your response I used an application Scanoss https://www.scanoss.com/. I will investigate. But the application cannot use the trusted root certificate ?

Comment: Does the PolarProxy pem file show up in `/etc/ssl/certs` after you've added it? If so, then you can verify that it's installed properly with:
`openssl s_client -connect www.netresec.com:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs`

@sectrain However, not all applications rely on the certs installed in `/etc/ssl/certs`. For example, this blog post explains how to install custom certs for Java, Python, Node JS and Go:
https://blog.ropnop.com/proxying-cli-tools/

Comment: Thansk you very much